# Why system.out.println changes reflects without building jar?

Tags: java, maven, println, system.out, build-tools

I am using maven as a build tool and running some integration-test cases. I logged some statements in my test case using `System.out.println()` and did a `mvn verify` and even i didn't `clean install/package` the jar.The changes were reflecting for logging statements. Did the mvn verify implicitly does a `install/package` or it doesn't require building the jar. If any one have any idea please share.

Comment: Testing tests the code; it doesn't package it.

Comment: See [the build lifecyle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html): verify is after package but before install. in your case package is enough since that's when the jar is built...

Comment: @Dave : I know testing test the code therefore i asked the question how the logger statements are reflected without building the jar.

Comment: Because testing tests, if doesn't package.

Comment: @Anandj.Kadhi why unaccept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven goal `verify` comes after package see: [Maven Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) so the packaging occurs.

Answer (score 0):

See mvn build lifecycle for order (all above are used) https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html :

```
validate         - validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available
compile          - compile the source code of the project
test             - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or deployed
package          - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
integration-test - process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run
verify           - run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria
install          - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally
deploy           - done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.
```